# Selecting the same column from Different rows Based on Different Criteria

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

My table creates a row for each customer name for the unique customer number.

```
CREATE TABLE #src(Number int, name varchar(32), seq bit);

INSERT #src(Number,name,seq) VALUES
(12345,'Mickey Mouse',0),
(12345,'Minnie Mouse',1),
(45678,'Donald Duck',0),
(45678,'Daphney Duck',1),
(245678,'Pluto Dog',0);
```

I need to be able to return a single row with multiple name columns based on the "Seq" number. It will always either be a 0 or a 1 and the Seq 1 can sometimes be blank.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Given this table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE #src(Number int, name varchar(32), seq bit);

INSERT #src(Number,name,seq) VALUES
(12345,'Mickey Mouse',0),
(12345,'Minnie Mouse',1),
(45678,'Donald Duck',0),
(45678,'Daphney Duck',1),
(245678,'Pluto Dog',0);
```

You can apply a simple `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT Number, Owner1 = [0], Owner2 = COALESCE([1],'')
  FROM #src AS c
  PIVOT (MAX(name) FOR seq IN ([0],[1])) AS p
  ORDER BY Number;
```

Results:

```
number   Owner1         Owner2
------   ------------   ------------
12345    Mickey Mouse   Minnie Mouse
45678    Donald Duck    Daphney Duck
245678   Pluto Dog
```

I would just ensure that `Number, seq` is enforced to be unique and that `seq` is either a bit or has a constraint so that it can only be `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 1):

**Another method without using pivot**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer(Number int, [Name] varchar(255),Seq bit);
INSERT INTO dbo.Customer(Number,[Name],Seq)
VALUES
(12345,'Mickey Mouse',0),
(12345,'Minnie Mouse',1),
(45678,'Donald Duck',0),
(45678,'Daphney Duck',1),
(245678,'Pluto Dog',0);

SELECT  Number, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN Seq = 0 THEN [Name] END) as Owner1, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN Seq = 1 Then [Name] END) AS Owner2
FROM dbo.Customer
GROUP BY Number;
```

**Result**

```
Number  Owner1  Owner2
12345   Mickey Mouse    Minnie Mouse
45678   Donald Duck Daphney Duck
245678  Pluto Dog   NULL
```

---

**Update: Issue with many columns**

If the other columns mentioned in the comments are the same based on the number, you can add them to the group by, and cast the `TEXT` value as `varchar(4000)`  *(max 3640 datalength)* Otherwise you would have to choose one of the two with `MAX` / `MIN` / `...`

```
SELECT  Number, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN Seq = 0 THEN [Name] END) as Owner1, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN Seq = 1 Then [Name] END) AS Owner2
        ,[Street1], [Street2], [City] , [State] , [Zipcode] , [HomePhone] ,CAST(JobMemo as varchar(4000))
FROM dbo.Debtors
GROUP BY Number,[Street1], [Street2], [City] , [State] , [Zipcode] , [HomePhone] ,CAST(JobMemo as varchar(4000));
```

*Disclaimer: the performance will probably not be optimal*

Comment: OK thank you! So there's pretty much no way to run a simle query without creating a table first?

Comment: @NicoleMontez No problem, I am not sure what you mean by the 'without creating a table first'? I could have created a temp table aswell. As far as questions go, giving the sample data + table create statement really helps! We always have to create a table with the same sample data to show a valid resultset as an answer :).

Comment: Error on Pivot table: Pivot grouping columns must be comparable. The type of column "JobMemo" is "text", which is not comparable.                                                                                                                                                                        
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Debtors](
 [Number] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Seq] [int] NULL,
 [Name] [varchar](30) NULL,
 [Street1] [varchar](30) NULL,
 [Street2] [varchar](30) NULL,
 [City] [varchar](30) NULL,
 [State] [varchar](3) NULL,
 [Zipcode] [varchar](10) NULL,
 [HomePhone] [varchar](30) NULL,

Comment: @NicoleMontez does the JobMemo need to be text? What does `SELECT MAX(DATALENGTH(JobMemo)) from dbo.Debtors` return? Maybe you could change it to varchar or nvarchar datatype? You could also cast it in the query. Could you add the entire table to the question?

Comment: It's HUGE. I couldn't fit all of the characters. I'm sorry, this is my first question. I normally just wing it on my own. I inherited this table, and it's very invloved.

Comment: Here are the results of the quesry you asked me to run.                  
(No column name)
3640

Comment: Alright, no problem, the text column could in theory be casted / changed to varchar / nvarchar(4000). However if in the future bigger strings are inserted that might prove as an issue. The issue is when one of the other columns is different the query will not work